# How to properly manage votes in a voting app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, mern

I'm making a voting app using the MERN stack. I use mongoose and express for the database and back-end.

This is my Mongoose Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    //create a schema
    const CarrozaSchema = Schema({
      nombre: {
        type: String
      },
      curso: {
        type: String
      },
      votos: Number
    });

    module.exports = Carroza = mongoose.model("carroza", CarrozaSchema);
```

and this is the route that manage the votes:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Carroza model
const Carroza = require("../../models/Carroza");

// @route   POST api/votos
// @desc    Realizar el voto
// @access  public
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  Carroza.findOne({ nombre: req.body.nombre })
    .then(carroza => {
      if (!carroza) {
        return res.status(404).json(req.body);
      }

      carroza.votos = carroza.votos + 1; //Here is where the votes are update
      carroza.save();
      res.status(200).json(req.body);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the front-end the user has a list of "carrozas" with a button to add a vote to the one they choose.
[this is what the user sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3NTq.png)
The problem is that if two users vote for the same "carroza" at the same time only one vote is added.

Comment: I don't see the question. What are you tryin' to accomplish?

Comment: if two people vote for the same carroza at the same time (in two different devices) only one vote is counted, the other is lost. I want to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't see a problem with that code, still if that isn't working, try mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` with `$inc`. Here is an example:

```
Carroza.findOneAndUpdate({ nombre: req.body.nombre }, {$inc:{votos:1}}, function(err, result){
    if(err) res.json(err);  // whatever error
    else res.json(result);  // whatever result
})
```

This will also reduce the query time, as the code is short and runs single query instead of two.

These type of issues are generally faced in case of high traffic, and are solved by using technologies like Redis, RabbitMQ and Kafka.

Hope it helps! Let me know if it works.